# Save resized image with PHP GD in Storage:

Tags: php, laravel

I would appreciate it if you would help to decipher how I can save the modified image in
Storage::('users'). 
imagejpeg($imgResized$image_path_name,90); save it to me in the public root folder and save it with the modified size, but I don't want it in public, I want it in storage users. Thank you in advance.

```
$image_path = $request->file('image_path');
if ($image_path) {
    $image_path_name = time().$image_path->getClientOriginalName();

    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path);
    $imgResized = imagescale($img, 100);
    imagejpeg($imgResized, $image_path_name,90);
    imagedestroy($img);
    imagedestroy($imgResized);

    Storage::disk('users')->put($image_path_name, File::get($image_path));

    $user->image = $image_path_name;
}

    $user->update();
```

Comment: Hello @David and welcome to Stack Overflow, there's no such default disk named users, would be helpful if you show your `filesystem.php` config file where you're defining it

Comment: 'users' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/users'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ], Created by me to save user images. Thank you for your reply @caddy DZ.

Comment: check my updated answer, it's the `$to` parameter of `imagejpeg` is what you need